# Need a help to create hibernate query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

need a help to create hibernate query that table is jdwCustomerTlrdRef and it should take all the operation_spec = customer name. the method should return sysId.

Here is the code to review. Please help me i am new to this hibernate query.

public getCustomerTlrdRef(BigDecimal sysId) {

```
System.out.println("---- getAllCustomerTlrdRef " );

String query = "from JdwCustomerTlrdRef as jdwCustomerTlrdRef where jdwCustomerTlrdRef.operation_spec= '+customer_name+'";
Query q = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(query);
List<JdwCustomerTlrdRef> customerTlrdRefSysId = q.list();

System.out.println(" List size: " + customerTlrdRefSysId.size());

return customerTlrdRefSysId;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
String query = "from JdwCustomerTlrdRef jdwCustomerTlrdRef where jdwCustomerTlrdRef.operation_spec= '+ customer_name +'";
```

Otherwise if you want to pass the parameter later in your code then do it this way.

```
String query = "FROM JdwCustomerTlrdRef jdwCustomerTlrdRef WHERE jdwCustomerTlrdRef.operation_spec = :customer_name"
```

then in your code you can pass the parameter this way.

`query.setParameter("customer_name", theCustomerNameParameter)`;